# Strange validation conflict in Spring JPA TableGenerator

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, flyway

I have a legacy database with composite primary key in table `project`. (BaseEntity  contains common properties for lastModifiedDate and lastModifiedBy)

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProjectPk.class)
public class Project extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="nextProjectId")
    @TableGenerator(
            name="nextProjectId",
            table="projectId",
            pkColumnName = "proj_Id",
            pkColumnValue="proj_id"
    )
    private Long  projId;

    @Id
    private int version;

  //other properties, getters and setters omitted for clarity
}
```

PK class

```
public class ProjectPk implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int  projId;
    private int  version;

  //both constructoirs, equals, hashcode, getters and setters omitted for clarity
}
```

- I have flyway migration files to simulate production database.

```
drop table if exists project;
CREATE TABLE project
(
    proj_id             bigint,
    version             int,
    -- other columns omitted for clarity
    PRIMARY KEY (`proj_id`, `version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

drop table if exists project_id;
CREATE TABLE project_id
(
    proj_id             bigint
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

- flyway creates tables as ordered in migration file

```
Table: project_id
Columns:
proj_id bigint
...


Table: project
Columns:
proj_id bigint PK 
version int PK
...
```

during maven build I'm getting validation error

- `Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [proj_id] in table [project_id]; found [bigint (Types#BIGINT)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]`

What I did wrong to make hibernate expect `[varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]`?

This is SpringBoot project 2.6.6 with MySql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following problems with your code:

1. Type mismatch between `Project.projId` (Long type) and `ProjectPk.projId` (int type).
2. You use wrong table structure for the `project_id` table.

You can see a working example below.

Assuming that you have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_project
(
    proj_id   bigint,
    version   int,
    title     VARCHAR(50),
    
    PRIMARY KEY (proj_id, version)
);

create table table_identifier (
    table_name varchar(255) not null,
    product_id bigint,
    primary key (table_name)
);
insert into table_identifier values ('test_project', 20);
```

and the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_project")
@IdClass(ProjectPk.class)
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "nextProjectId")
    @TableGenerator(
        name="nextProjectId",
        table="table_identifier",
        pkColumnName = "table_name",
        valueColumnName="product_id",
        allocationSize = 5
    )
    @Column(name = "proj_id")
    private Long  projId;

    @Id
    private int version;

    // other fields, getters, setters ...
}
```

you will be able to persist the entity like below:

```java
Project project = new Project();
project.setVersion(1);
// ...
entityManager.persist(project);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible to have table_identifier without column "table_name varchar(255) not null,"? Unfortunately, the legacy database table does not have this column. Maybe this is a problem, that Hibernate expects this column  by design (i.e. supposed to have multiple rows for each table), but legacy database doesn't have table-identifier column. My guess that whoever design db layout had in mind something like "generated db sequence".

Comment: I got it! I've misinterpreted the meaning of `pkColumnName = "proj_Id"`. Let me try to play with it.

Comment: See [this part](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-table) of the hibernate documentation. By default hibernate use table `hibernate_sequences`

Comment: I think it is not possible to have `table_identifier` without column `table_name`, because hibernate use this table for storing the current sequence value for each table that use `GenerationType.TABLE` strategy.

Comment: Thanks, I really need to convince DBA to alter the sequence table created 20 years ago ))).